# convert .slk data into .csv float

Tags: python, csv, slk

I had some data x & y in .slk format. However, when i read the .slk data it gives me the data in string format and i am unable to convert this string data into float data. Is there any ways that i can do this in python instead of manually saving the .slk format into .csv format as i am trying to automate the whole process.

[image]

Or does anyone know how can python read .slk format and convert it into .csv format.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try [slk-parser](https://pypi.org/project/sylk-parser/) ?

Comment: yes i did, but i couldnt convert the values from string to float. and i cant seems to remove the quote " " outside the values.

Comment: You can read it into a pandas dataframe from CSV and modify data types on that?

Comment: i did try with pandas dataframe too. however, i am getting gibberish results and all the data ended up in a single column instead of two column

Comment: have you been able to find a solution ?